# de-referencing pointer using with &->

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct, member-access

I have simple the nested structure:

```
struct abc {
        int i;
};

struct milan {
        struct abc obj;
};

int main()
{
    struct milan *ptr; 
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct milan)); 
    ptr->obj.i = 10;    
    printf("%d\n", ptr->obj); 
}
```

It prints `10`, but how the de-reference a pointer taking place here, is `ptr->obj` the same as `&->obj == *obj` ?

Comment: `ptr->obj` is the same as `(*ptr).obj`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The seemingly random keystrokes of `&->obj == *obj` notwithstanding, is you real question how `10` is being emitted, since you never actually sent `ptr->obj.i` to `printf` ? First, you're lying to `printf`. You're telling it you're sending an `int` and instead you sent a `abc`. However, in this case, an `abc` happens to have an `int` as its first and only member. Add a member on either side of that `i` and watch the fireworks. Then stop doing all of the above.

Comment: The statement `printf("%d\n", ptr->obj);` exhibits undefined behaviour.  If you turn your compiler warning level up (`-Wall` on `gcc` or `clang`) you should get a diagnostic message along the lines of `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct abc’ [-Wformat=]` .

Comment: And fwiw, the whole dynamic allocation and `milan` are irrelevant here, add confusion to the issue, and are thus a red herring. You could just as easily have ill-advisedly done `struct abc obj; obj.i=10; printf("%d\n", obj);`. Turn up your warnings and treat them as errors (because that's exactly what they are).

Comment: _"is `ptr->obj` same as `&->obj == *obj`"_. No, it's not the same. `ptr->obj` is the same as `(*ptr).obj`, and `&->obj == *obj` is totally meaningless.

Comment: You probably want `printf("%d\n", ptr->obj.i)` instead of `printf("%d\n", ptr->obj)`, latter being undefined behaviour.

Comment: Try `printf( "%d\n", *p );` and the program will again print "10"... Mysterious... (Do NOT do this in real life...)

Comment: @Fe2O3, no it's not mysterious, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Definitely a no-no! However, it is 'experiments' like this that teach that `obj` is 0 bytes offset from the start of the memory block, as is `obj.i`... It's how one develops the mental imagery to understand more complex ideas... Cheers!

Comment: @Fe2O3 "Undefined behavior" is a technical term that describes what we have here. The standard does not _define_ how an implementation _behaves_. So, if you write `obj`, which is clearly of type `struct abc`, and interpret it as `int`, it only "works" if the specific compiler inserted no padding and the offset of `i` in `obj` is 0. If it "works" with one compiler, it does not need to work with another compiler.

Comment: Fe203, Yeah I see, ptr is pointing to a memory block that is start of both struct milan and struct abc. I am just confused how ptr->ob is same as (*ptr).obj?

Comment: `a->b` is just shorthand for `(*a).b`. It makes code more readable.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, in my head, I am just thinking if this (*a).b , still breakdown further, something like (*a) is de-referencing the address pointed by a which is struct abc and then .b mean accessing offset at  byte 0, but not sure this make sense to you ?

Comment: @Milan I think you should get a good C book for starters.

Comment: `ptr->obj` is the same as `(*ptr).obj` because that's the definition of the `->` operator.  It makes things like `a->b->c` possible, which is far more readable than `(*(*a).b).c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `ptr->obj` is the same as `( *ptr ).obj`.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.3 Structure and union members)

> 4 A postfix expression followed by the -> operator and an identifier
> designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that
> of the named member of the object to which the first expression
> points, and is an lvalue.96) If the first expression is a pointer to a
> qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of
> the designated member

and

> 3 A postfix expression followed by the . operator and an identifier
> designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that
> of the named member,95) and is an lvalue if the first expression is an
> lvalue. If the first expression has qualified type, the result has the
> so-qualified version of the type of the designated member.

Comment: Vlad, does it mean -> is de-reference operator , and it would de-reference anything that it points to, in this case , it is  de-referencing what is at address "struct abc", right ?

Comment: @Milan It is not a dereference operator because it does not dereference the pointed  object. It is a member access operator by means of a pointer. The dereference operator is the unary operator *.

Comment: @Milan There is no need to introduce your own terms. Use the terms defined in the C Standard.

Comment: @Milan Under the hood as I pointer out the operator ptr->obj can be evaluated like ( *ptr ).obj. That is the left side pointer can be dereferenced.